# Firebase transaction multiple updates

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a user rating system in my application where one user can rate another user with a 1-5 star rating as well as a description of their experience. I am having problems with the average rating system because my transaction can update only one table at a time per the documentation. Maybe i am going about it the wrong way and could use some advice or help.

The count field gets updated reliably, it will increment as it should in my testing. Its getting the average rating to calculate correctly that is not working. I think because i am trying to do two transactions in one function.

db:

```
"reputation" : {
    "userID123" : {
      "-LDXRfZPscamLvjDUbXb" : {
        "ratingUserID2" : {
          "rating" : 3,
          "description" : "You are awesome!"
        }
      },
      "asdfsdfsdf3333" : {
        "ratingUserID3" : {
          "rating" : 4,
          "description" : "Great work."
        }
      }
      "count" : 2,
      "rating" : 3.5
    }
  },
...other data...
```

firebase function:

```
exports.calculateReputation = functions.database.ref('/reputation/{userID}/{uniqueID}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const data = snap.val();
    const rating = data[Object.keys(data)].rating;

    snap.ref.parent.child('/count').transaction((currentCount) => {
        return currentCount + 1;
    }, (error, committed, snapshot) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Transaction failed abnormally!', error);
        } else if (!committed) {
            console.log('We aborted the transaction (because ada already exists).');
        } else {
            console.log('added!');
            console.log('ADD RATING:', rating);
        }
        var count = snapshot.val();
        console.log('COUNT:', count);
        snap.ref.parent.child('/rating').transaction((currentRating) => {
            var newRating = Math.round( ((rating + currentRating) / count) * 10 ) / 10;
            return newRating;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Perhaps the bigger problem is that you're not returning a promise from the function that resolves when all async work is complete in that function.

Comment: @DougStevenson You mean returning data to .transaction.then()?

Comment: Any time you deal with something that returns a promise, like transaction(), it needs to be taken into account for the final returned promise.